# remove xml lines that has registry keys in the attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to delete the xml lines with attribute `reg` that has registry keys and create a new xml file. Below is the example code for reference.

```
<file name="CMS_1.zip" version="1.01" reg="~/data/CMS_1.zip"/>
<file name="CMS_2.zip" version="1.01" reg="~/data/CMS_2.zip"/>
<file name="2012_3.swf" version="1.01" reg="~/data/Assets/CMS/V/Assets/FlashFiles/2012_3.swf"/>
<file name="WS4.zip" version="1.01" reg="~/3b65566e-6y7c-a460-80bf-3612e36pp9ku/data/WS4.zip"/>
<file name="Inv5.zip" version="1.02" reg="~/d465534r-a20c-558r-80bf-3612e687d45g/data/Inv5.zip"/>
<file name="Inv6.zip" version="1.01" reg="~/4567j66e-y89o-4074-80bf-3612e247f1c7/data/Inv6.zip"/>
<file name="Inv7.zip" version="1.01" reg="~/3b0po99e-a20c-4p91-80bf-pp9ku363f4r5/data/Inv7.zip"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, your XML file must be valid with **root** element.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var doc = XDocument.Parse(/*XML file content*/); // or use XDocument.Load(...)
var pattern = @".*[0-9a-zA-Z]{8}\-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}\-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}\-[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}\-[0-9a-zA-Z]{12}.*";
doc.Descendants("file")
    .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch((string)x.Attribute("reg"), pattern))
    .Remove();
var xmlContent = doc.ToString(); // or just doc.Save()
```